# Yavanna's alarm clock

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

After the fall of the Lamps, Yavanna decreed that most of the living things in Arda should sleep until light returned.  She then gathered up the available light and made the Two Trees to illuminate Valinor.

The Sleep of Yavanna ended with the first rising of the Sun and Moon; but this happened only because Ungoliant killed the Two Trees, which surely was not in Yavanna's plan.

So, if not for Ungoliant, how did Yavanna (or the Valar in general) intend for the Sleep to end?

Answer (score 5):

According to the "Ainulindalë," the Ainur were given a brief view of the future development of Arda, before they descended into the world.  This glimpse told them much about what would happen, but it was too quick for them to study the world in detail.  However, we know that what the Valar saw affected their subsequent work on the construction of Arda.  Based on his memories of what he had seen of the forthcoming Children of Ilúvatar (the races of elves and men), Aulë created the dwarves.  His spouse Yavanna would similarly have seen that, past some point in time, the whole of the Earth would be illuminated by a light source that would not fail until the final battle of Dagor Dagorath.

Comment: Why did you roll back the edit which added proper Tolkienian punctuation as well as correcting the typos?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Also, I thought it looked better with the paragraph breaks as well. All in all, revision 2 was the best one...